# Updating GeoTools 18.1 to 22.4 migration issue

Tags: geotools

My working code using GeoTools 18.1 is below:
for example:

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry out = pGeom.buffer(distance.doubleValue(unit));
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry retGeom = out;
// reproject the geometry to the original projection
if (!(origCRS instanceof ProjectedCRS)) {

    retGeom = JTS.transform(out, fromTransform);

  } catch (MismatchedDimensionException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  } catch (org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException e) {
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

The issue is JTS.transform(...), expects something called an Envelope and not a Geometry.  How do I convert a Gemoetry into an Envelope class for the latest GeoTools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been a number of changes in GeoTools since 18.1 which are documented in the [upgrade faq](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html), of which the most important in your case is the change to JTS 1.16+

> Package change to org.locationtech.jts
>
> This release changes the package names from com.vividsolutions.jts to
> org.locationtech.jts. To update your own code follow the [JTS Upgrade](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/MIGRATION.md)
> Guide instructions.
>
> Using the command line to update your own pom.xml files:
>
> git grep -l com.vividsolutions | grep pom.xml | xargs sed -i "s/com.vividsolutions/org.locationtech.jts/g"
>
> And codebase:
>
> git grep -l com.vividsolutions | xargs sed -i
> "s/com.vividsolutions/org.locationtech/"

So you need to import the following for it to continue working:

```
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
```

And due to the units changes at 24.x you will also need to change:

> The Units library (JSR 385) was updated to Units 2.0. This is mostly a
> change from package tec.uom.se.* to tech.units.indriya.*. If you make
> any use of the Units library in your own code you will need to update
> the imports. There are also changes to the arithmetic operations’
> names. See this [blog post](https://schneide.blog/tag/unit-api-2-0/) for more details.

```
import tec.uom.se.quantity.Quantities;
import tec.uom.se.unit.MetricPrefix;
```

to

```
import javax.measure.MetricPrefix;
import tech.units.indriya.quantity.Quantities;
```

There were other Units changes in earlier versions but I have lost those in the latest update and you may as well go to the latest version or you'll have more issues sooner.